# Prolog Binary search algorithm

Tags: prolog

so trying to do a binary search algorithm in prolog

```
%checks to see if a value is contained in a list of integers, 
%using binary search tactics

%success base case
%A list contains a value if its center is the value
contains(List, Value):- even_division(_, [Value|_], List).

%case that Value is large
%A list contains a value if the value is larger than the center,
%and the second half of the list contains the value
contains(List, Value):- even_division(_, [Center|SecondHalf], List), 
                        Center<Value, SecondHalf \= [], 
                        contains(SecondHalf, Value).

%case that Value is small
%A list contains a value if the value is smaller than the center, 
%and the first half of the list contains the value
contains(List, Value):- even_division(FirstHalf, [Center|_], List), 
                         Center>Value, FirstHalf\=[],  
                         contains(FirstHalf, Value). 

%even_division(First, Second, Xs) is true when
% Xs is the concatenation of First and Second,
% and First and Second are either the same length
% or Second is one element longer than first.
even_division(First, Second, Xs) :- append(First, Second, Xs), 
                                    length(First,F), length(Second,S),  
                                    S>=F, S-F=<1.
```

however what i want to do is instead of typing out a list i want to create it base on a number of items i want it, so say i want to do a binary search on list of 5000 items, obviously i cant type 5000 items into therem so how could i generate it?

Comment: so i figured i could generate list like this `% range(I,K,L) :- I <= K, and L is the list containing all 
%    consecutive integers from I to K.
%    (integer,integer,list) (+,+,?)

range(I,I,[I]).
range(I,K,[I|L]) :- I < K, I1 is I + 1, range(I1,K,L).` However how can i combine both now.

Answer (score 1):

your code seems rather inefficient, for sure doesn't exhibit log(N) behaviour. I tested it using [numlist](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=numlist/3)/3, and [time](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=time/1)/1

```
?- numlist(1,10,L),contains(L,7).
% 279,957 inferences, 1.701 CPU in 1.706 seconds (100% CPU, 164557 Lips)
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...] 

?- numlist(1,100000,L),time(contains(L,17)).
% 2,800,016 inferences, 258.828 CPU in 262.601 seconds (99% CPU, 10818 Lips)
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...]
```

it's linear in number of inferences, but quadratic in execution time. Probably the memory overhead introduced by list splitting it's severe. numlist/3 is a list generator, like your range/3.